# avfoundation: appendPixelBuffer withPresentationTime, adaptor not ready

Tags: iphone, uiimage, adapter, avfoundation

I use the following code to create a video from a sequence of images stored into an array (takenImages). Duration is the frame duration in seconds.

Everything is then saved to library.

My problem is that if I run with debugger on, the video is saved perfectly but if I run without debugger the video is not saved entirely (just the first frames were saved).

```
int timescale = duration * [takenImages count];

    for (int i = 0; i < [takenImages count]; i++) {
        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[takenImages objectAtIndex:i] CGImage]];

        BOOL append_ok = NO;
        int j = 0;
        while (!append_ok && j < 30) {
            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
                printf("appending %d attemp %d\n", i, j);
                append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(i*duration,timescale)];
            } else {
                printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", i, j);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            }
            j++;
        }

        if (!append_ok) {
            printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", i, j);
        }

    }
```

this is an example of what I have in console after running (debugger off):

```
appending 0 attemp 0
appending 1 attemp 0
adaptor not ready 2, 0
adaptor not ready 2, 1
adaptor not ready 2, 2
adaptor not ready 2, 3
adaptor not ready 2, 4
adaptor not ready 2, 5
adaptor not ready 2, 6
adaptor not ready 2, 7
adaptor not ready 2, 8
adaptor not ready 2, 9
adaptor not ready 2, 10
adaptor not ready 2, 11
adaptor not ready 2, 12
adaptor not ready 2, 13
adaptor not ready 2, 14
adaptor not ready 2, 15
adaptor not ready 2, 16
adaptor not ready 2, 17
adaptor not ready 2, 18
adaptor not ready 2, 19
adaptor not ready 2, 20
adaptor not ready 2, 21
adaptor not ready 2, 22
adaptor not ready 2, 23
adaptor not ready 2, 24
adaptor not ready 2, 25
adaptor not ready 2, 26
adaptor not ready 2, 27
adaptor not ready 2, 28
adaptor not ready 2, 29
error appending image 2 times 30
adaptor not ready 3, 0
adaptor not ready 3, 1
adaptor not ready 3, 2
adaptor not ready 3, 3
adaptor not ready 3, 4
adaptor not ready 3, 5
adaptor not ready 3, 6
adaptor not ready 3, 7
adaptor not ready 3, 8
adaptor not ready 3, 9
adaptor not ready 3, 10
adaptor not ready 3, 11
adaptor not ready 3, 12
adaptor not ready 3, 13
adaptor not ready 3, 14
adaptor not ready 3, 15
adaptor not ready 3, 16
adaptor not ready 3, 17
adaptor not ready 3, 18
adaptor not ready 3, 19
adaptor not ready 3, 20
adaptor not ready 3, 21
adaptor not ready 3, 22
adaptor not ready 3, 23
adaptor not ready 3, 24
adaptor not ready 3, 25
adaptor not ready 3, 26
adaptor not ready 3, 27
adaptor not ready 3, 28
adaptor not ready 3, 29
error appending image 3 times 30
adaptor not ready 4, 0
adaptor not ready 4, 1
adaptor not ready 4, 2
adaptor not ready 4, 3
adaptor not ready 4, 4
adaptor not ready 4, 5
adaptor not ready 4, 6
adaptor not ready 4, 7
adaptor not ready 4, 8
adaptor not ready 4, 9
adaptor not ready 4, 10
adaptor not ready 4, 11
adaptor not ready 4, 12
adaptor not ready 4, 13
adaptor not ready 4, 14
adaptor not ready 4, 15
adaptor not ready 4, 16
adaptor not ready 4, 17
adaptor not ready 4, 18
adaptor not ready 4, 19
adaptor not ready 4, 20
adaptor not ready 4, 21
adaptor not ready 4, 22
adaptor not ready 4, 23
adaptor not ready 4, 24
adaptor not ready 4, 25
adaptor not ready 4, 26
adaptor not ready 4, 27
adaptor not ready 4, 28
adaptor not ready 4, 29
error appending image 4 times 30
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance.

bye
Tommaso

Answer (score 5):

try this when setting the buffers.

```
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:presentTime];
if(buffer)
    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
```

Comment: thank you Jeff, it works now! All images were appended at first attempt!

Comment: Working perfect for me :)

Answer (score 2):

writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

Comment: thanks, I added this command (checked also documentation and it is clearly needed in my case) but the result is one more frame appended, then again adaptor never become ready

Answer (score 2):

It is more proper to use `requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:usingBlock:` on your writerInput object.  When it is ready for input again it'll call the block again.

Comment: I still needed to use a sleep to get it working properly.  Terrible.